# How do I do exception handling inside of a using block?

Tags: c#

I'm just wondering why would the C# language not allow you to include a catch block after a using statement like so:

```
using(var MyObject = new MyObject())
{
    // do work
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // log/handle exception
}
```

This issue has been around for a long time, and it seems like a feature that would be easy to implement, have no adverse effects, and would actually be used by virtually every programmer. Is there a legitimate reason the C# language hasn't been updated to allow for this or has there just not been enough demand for the feature?

EDIT: One (or more?) of my comments below mentioned the shortcoming the using block when it comes to WCF. However, I later realized I was in err as it applies to this conversation because the problem there is with exceptions being raised in the (auto-generated) finally block whereas what I am asking for here is access to the catch block that would be between the try and finally if the using statement were to generate one.

Comment: I don't see how it makes sense to add this without adding it to, e.g., the end of an `if` chain as well. And as Eric keeps repeating, the benefit from this over putting a `try` around it would not be enough to implement it over another feature.

Comment: Wow, people really hate this question, haha.

Comment: @chris Can you point me to what Eric said?

Comment: The `using` statement is not meant for catching exceptions. It's meant to be used to ensure that `Dispose()` is called even if you have an exception. It's the equivilent of doing a `Try/Catch/Finally` and putting the `Dispose()` in the `Finally`.

Comment: @ZivS That's pretty much what I expected I'd hear :)

Comment: `using` serves as an indicator that something is going to be cleaned up, saves you from remembering to explicitly call `Dispose`, and gracefully handles exceptions. That's a big benefit over writing it yourself every time.

Comment: @BVernon, It's probably in half of his answers on here by now.

Comment: "I would then ask why they bothered to write the using statement in the first place" - because most of the time you need a using statement, you *don't* need a catch block...

Comment: @chris I would argue that it DOES NOT always gracefully handle exceptions. In fact it eats them in certain scenarios, especially when used with WCF.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a rant in disguise.

Comment: @ChrisDunaway I actually knew what you meant, but that doesn't address the question. There are times you want control over the catch portion and you have to nest it inside a try/catch. But wouldn't it be cleaner if you DIDN'T have to nest it and could override the catch that using generates?

Comment: @BVernon: The emitted code from a `using` does not include a `catch`, it is a `finally`.

Comment: @JonSkeet Really? You don't expect and log exceptions when doing any kind of IO operation?

Comment: @Guvante Thanks, point is the same though. Instead of 'overriding' it's catch block, pretend I said 'add' a catch block.

Comment: @BVernon When JonSkeet codes, IO Exceptions catch and log themselves out of respect.

Comment: @BVernon: I typically only catch the exception at a higher level, and log the exception there. I have far more `using` statements than `catch` blocks.

Comment: I think the important takeaway here is that newbies might misunderstand how these two syntactic bits of sugar are different from each other.  I don't think this is a completely useless question, though the title should be changed so as not to mislead others.

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/06/22/why-doesn-t-c-implement-top-level-methods.aspx

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 Why did you change the title? I know how to do exception  handling inside a using block and that's clearly not what the question was about... at all??

Comment: @BVernon your title could be very misleading to newbies, as using blocks are similar but distinct from exception handling.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 So that means you need to change it to ask something that has absolutely nothing to do with what I'm actually asking? THAT's misleading.

Comment: @Pheonixblade9 Ask yourself is this question about how to do exception handling inside a using block? No, it is not. It's a question about why a language feature doesn't exist. If you're going to change it, change it to something that still reflects the actual question please.

Answer (score 6):

To answer the primary question of "how do you combine exception handling and the using construct". The answer is usually in my case I do not. Most of my exception handling is handled at a higher point in the call stack, centralized to simplify logging and knowing what to do next (for instance if I were enumerating a set of items I would catch at the enumeration step to allow me to log that the item failed but continue with the remaining items).

However if I were to combine the two I would wrap the `using` in a try/catch. You mentioned elsewhere the problem with doing this with WCF objects, as they have a tendency to have `Dispose()` methods that throw. In that case I would follow Microsoft's recommendation and not use them at all, instead manually expanding them.

I would go so far as to add logic to the `finally` block that has whatever logic is necessary to ensure that I do not call `Dispose()` in situations where it would throw an exception.

To answer your questions about a new language feature, your analysis is incorrect.

> This issue has been around for a long time

What issue? You pointed to a potential syntactic construct without justifying the purpose and claimed it is important. Syntactic constructs face a large requirement of features before being added.

There is a slight issue around WCF but it sounds like an API problem, not a language design one. If you read through the recommendations they effectively say "closing a connection is not exception free so manually verify that it is safe to do so before doing so".

> it seems like a feature that would be easy to implement

Research the `using` construct and you will relize it is actually complex to implement. The `using` construct expands to: (approximately)

```
MyObject MyObject;
try
{
    MyObject = new MyObject()
    // do work
}
finally
{
    if (MyObject != null)
        MyObject.Dispose();
}
```

By adding a `catch` you need to reorder things to get things to happen in the correct syntactic order (since `catch` goes before `finally`).

> have no adverse effects

You may have noticed but I glossed over why this is false. Where does the `catch` go? Do you add it as a second `try` to ensure the object is disposed before the `catch` block is executed (matching the apparent order in the syntax) or do you add it before the finally?

The former is trivial to implement on your own with a `try` and the later is hard to understand, and probably doesn't work right anyway as you don't catch exceptions in the implicit `finally` block.

> would actually be used by virtually every programmer

Most people would never do this, and instead prefer to use an explicit `try`/`catch` to ensure the purpose of the try/catch is explicit. Also watch out for overusing try/catch, as it is a bad habit to get into.

Comment: I believe by "no adverse effects" he meant it would not break any existing code for the simple reason that no existing code would make use of the feature and hence would be unaffected by it.

Comment: You're making this sound more complicated than it is and throwing in an oddball possibility for how it might be implemented.  The Using/Catch block would mimick a Try/Catch/Finally block that you otherwise have to write yourself. It's syntactic sugar.

Comment: @BVernon: Either you put it around (which saves you writing 5 characters `try {}`) or you put it inside (which unexpectedly fails to catch exceptions in the `Dispose()` method).

Answer (score 3):

You can easily achieve this goal by wrapping the using in a try block, thusly:

```
try
{
     using (var MyObject = new MyObject())
     {
          //do work
     }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
     //handle exception.
}
```

So the question becomes, why WOULD the designers tie the concept of exception handling (i.e., the `try`/`catch`) blocks with the concept of resource disposal (i.e., the `using` statement)?  It would further complicate the language, as now instead of having a single well-defined place that a `catch` can appear, (after a `try`) it now has other rules as well (why stop with usings?  Why not then say you can add a `catch` after any arbitrary `{}` pair?)

It's probably not worth the effort for a feature that would add confusion and does not add any real value.

Comment: When using WCF services, you can't use using statements (see https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa355056(v=vs.110).aspx). You don't think it would be useful there?

Comment: And agree to disagree about how it might be confusing. The argument that you wouldn't want to do it because then why not add catch after any arbitrary enclosure is pure silliness IMO.

Comment: @BVernon: But you are just making things more confusing. You would have to inject before the `finally` and could never catch the error in `Dispose()` (which just introduces a different reason to avoid `using`).